# importing app engine sample in eclipse

Tags: google-app-engine

Downloaded GAE sample code and copied into Eclipse pydev explorer
and got following errors on execution

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\dev_appserver.py", line 67, in <module>
    run_file(__file__, globals())
  File "C:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\dev_appserver.py", line 63, in run_file
    execfile(script_path, globals_)
  File "C:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\dev_appserver_main.py", line 417, in <module>
    sys.exit(main(sys.argv))
  File "C:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\dev_appserver_main.py", line 360, in main
    config, matcher = dev_appserver.LoadAppConfig(root_path, {})
  File "C:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\dev_appserver.py", line 3441, in LoadAppConfig
    raise AppConfigNotFoundError
google.appengine.tools.dev_appserver.AppConfigNotFoundError
```

Answer (score 2):

This error occurs commonly if you don't have `app.yaml` or `dev_appserver` didn't find it.  Can you ensure that you ran `dev_appserver .` with the project directory being the working directory?  Also, please include app.yaml in your question, if the file actually exists.